# Align nested menu to right of parent nested menu

Tags: css

I want my second level of menu to drop down straight underneath the first and then levels under this to open out exactly to the right.

I've got the second nested menu working correctly but I can't figure out how to get the third level to go neatly to the right.  The way I have it now it overlaps.

Here is snippet, if anyone can hep me out I'd appreciate it thanks:

```css
#menu-main-menu-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font: 300 16px/16px Lato, Arial; }
  #menu-main-menu-container ul {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }
    #menu-main-menu-container ul ul {
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      margin-top: 15px; }
      #menu-main-menu-container ul ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0; }
  #menu-main-menu-container ul li {
    right: 50%;
    background-color: #f4f4f4; }
  #menu-main-menu-container li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
    #menu-main-menu-container li:hover > ul {
      display: block; }
  #menu-main-menu-container a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue; }
  #menu-main-menu-container li:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    transition: 1s; }
  #menu-main-menu-container li:hover > a {
    color: white; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=top-nav-menu.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="top-nav-menu.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu-main-menu-container">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Hidden Sub Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hidden Sub Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hidden Sub Item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#menu-main-menu-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font: 300 16px/16px Lato, Arial; }
  #menu-main-menu-container ul {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }
    #menu-main-menu-container ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: none;
    left: 0px;
    right: 6px;
    }
      #menu-main-menu-container ul ul ul {
            /* position: absolute; */
    /* top: 0; */
    float: none;
    /* left: 0px; */
    left: 0px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    left: 120px;
      
      
      }
  #menu-main-menu-container ul li {
    right: 50%;
    background-color: #f4f4f4; }
  #menu-main-menu-container li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
    #menu-main-menu-container li:hover > ul {
      display: block; }
  #menu-main-menu-container a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue; }
  #menu-main-menu-container li:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    transition: 1s; }
  #menu-main-menu-container li:hover > a {
    color: white; }
```

```html
<div id="menu-main-menu-container">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Hidden Sub Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hidden Sub Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hidden Sub Item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Check this Jsfiddle `code` for the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naya4ahs/

Comment: The problem with doing it like that is the sub menus then have to all be the same width. I was trying to figure out how to make it align to the right of the other menu in relation to the other.

Comment: Hold on for a moment. I'll give you the solution.

Comment: @Guerrilla: Here is a clean version: http://jsfiddle.net/s9ncomj2/
You can adapt your code with this.

Comment: @ user1012181 Just got back to computer.  It's lost it's central alignment so gonna have a look at code and see if it's compatibile.  I was trying to build a menu using this method of centering: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support but I keep getting stuck on the nested menus.  I think maybe if it is centered like that then a fixed width for submenus is mandatory

Comment: I think you can head start with this code and configure what you want.

Comment: Glad that it helped you!